# Sending multiple sensor data from arduino to python,any idea?

Tags: python, arduino

So I have this problem,I'm trying to send sensor data from arduino to python through serial communication.
But the output is a kind of wierd.
Does anyone have an idea on this?

Arduino code: to send sensor data

```
void setup(){

Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop(){

int sensor1 = 20;
int sensor2 = 40;
int sensor3 = 60;
Serial.write(sensor1);

}
```

python code: to receive sent data from arduino

```
import serial,time
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM1",9600,timeout=1)
while True:
    data = ser.read()
    time.sleep(1) 
    print("data:",data)
```

output :

```
data: b'\x14'
```

target :

```
data: 20
```

second target : sending multiple sensor data in a single serial.write().

```
data: 20 40 60
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `Serial.write()` on the arduino side, you are sending the sensor integers as **single byte value characters,** (as mentioned here in the [reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/)) but on the receiving side seem to be expecting whole lines of input (readline()). The value printed, `b'\x14'` (hexadecimal 14) is decimal 20, so the transmission was actually correct.    You can solve your problem by sending actual text integers from the arduino with:

```
Serial.println(sensor1);
```